# PrimeNg 12 p-calendar UTC issue

Tags: calendar, primeng, utc

I've a problem with PrimeNg Calendar component. I need to remove UTC from selected value in calendar. Selecting a date in the calendar component, the form value is:

```
Wed Jun 01 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Ora legale dell’Europa centrale)
```

so when i call a rest service passing this value, it is converted into:

```
"2022-05-31T22:00:00.000Z"
```

I know it's a problem related to UTC but I can't find a way to remove UTC setting attributes into p-calendar.
Is there a way to do this? Or it's possibile to manage the selected value into a directive?
I'm using PrimeNg 12.2.16

Answer (score 1):

For me I made a solution with a directive and date offset correction:

```
import { Calendar } from 'primeng/calendar';
import { Directive } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[utcCalendar]',
})
export class UtcCalendarDirective {

  constructor(private pCalendar: Calendar) {

    // Function was taken from
    // https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/calendar/calendar.ts

    pCalendar.updateModel = (value) => {
      pCalendar.value = value;

      if (pCalendar.dataType == 'date') {
        // Changes
        const date = new Date(pCalendar.value);
        date.setTime( date.getTime() + (-date.getTimezoneOffset())*60*1000 );
        pCalendar.onModelChange(date);
      }
      else if (pCalendar.dataType == 'string') {
        if (pCalendar.isSingleSelection()) {
          pCalendar.onModelChange(pCalendar.formatDateTime(pCalendar.value));
        }
        else {
          let stringArrValue = null;
          if (pCalendar.value) {
            stringArrValue = pCalendar.value.map((date: any) => pCalendar.formatDateTime(date));
          }
          pCalendar.onModelChange(stringArrValue);
        }
      }
    };
  }
}
```

And then when I do `value.toISOString()` It will give a date like `'2022-09-12T00:00:00.000Z'`.

Tested with forms. Outputs like `onSelect()` and some other functionality won't be changed but you can improve this code.